# Does the series $\sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \left[{\frac{1}{(-1)^n-5}}\right]^{n}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

$$\sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \left[{\frac{1}{(-1)^n-5}}\right]^{n}$$

I applied the root test and believe that this series converges. That is, I found that:

$$\text{limsup} \left|{\frac{1}{n} \left({\frac{1}{(-1)^n-5}}\right)^n}\right|^{\frac{1}{n}} <1$$

Can someone verify that I am correct. No need for a long proof. Thanks!

Comment: You are doing fine.

Answer (score 4):

The series $\sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \left({\frac{1}{(-1)^n-5}}\right)^n$ is absolutely convergent since $$\frac{1}{n}\cdot \left|{\frac{1}{(-1)^n-5}}\right|^n \leqslant \frac{1}{n}\cdot\dfrac{1}{4^n}.$$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{1 \over n}\bracks{1 \over \pars{-1}^{n} - 5}^{n}
=
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\braces{%
{1 \over 2n + 2}\,\bracks{1 \over \pars{-1}^{2n + 2} - 5}^{2n + 2}
+
{1 \over 2n + 1}\,\bracks{1 \over \pars{-1}^{2n + 1} - 5}^{2n + 1}}
\\[3mm]&=
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{%
{4^{-2n - 2} \over 2n + 2} - {6^{-2n - 1} \over 2n + 1}}
\end{align}

> $\ds{\fermi\pars{x} \equiv \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{x^{2n + 2} \over 2n + 2}\,,
>      \quad
>      {\rm g}\pars{x} \equiv \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{x^{2n + 1} \over 2n + 1}\,,
>      \quad\verts{x} < 1\,,\quad\fermi\pars{0} = {\rm g}\pars{0} = 0}$.
> \begin{align}
> \fermi'\pars{x} &= \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}x^{2n + 1} = {x \over 1 - x^{2}}
> =-\,{1 \over 2}\,\pars{{1 \over x - 1} + {1 \over x + 1}}
> \\[3mm]\imp &\fermi\pars{x}
> = -\,{1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{\bracks{x - 1}/\bracks{x + 1} \over -1}
> = -\,{1 \over 2}\ln\pars{1 - x \over 1 + x}
> = {1 \over 2}\ln\pars{1 + x \over 1 - x}
> \\&\mbox{Similarly,}
> \\
> {\rm g}\pars{x} &= \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}x^{2n} = {1 \over 1 - x^{2}}
> ={1 \over 2}\,\pars{{1 \over x + 1} - {1 \over x - 1}}
> \\[3mm]\imp &{\rm g}\pars{x}
> = {1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{\bracks{x + 1}/\bracks{x - 1} \over -1}
> = {1 \over 2}\ln\pars{1 + x \over 1 - x} = \fermi\pars{x}
> \end{align}

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{1 \over n}\bracks{1 \over \pars{-1}^{n} - 5}^{n}
=
\fermi\pars{1 \over 4} - \fermi\pars{1 \over 6}
=
{1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{5 \over 3} - {1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{7 \over 5} 
$$
$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{1 \over n}\bracks{1 \over \pars{-1}^{n} - 5}^{n}
\color{#000000}{\ =\ }
{1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{25 \over 21}} \approx 0.0872
$$

Answer (score 0):

Compare your series to the alternating harmonic series to see that it converges